# linux program does not start after sh gets killed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to start a program, which uses a serial port from within a bash script. The matter is that prior to doing that I need to kill "-sh" process in order to release the serial port occupied by it (I use a serial console and this is the only way to communicate with Linux). When I kill "-sh" my program doesn't start, however the bash script continues to execute. If I don't kill "-sh" my program normally starts. See code below for details:

```
#!/bin/bash
SH_PID=`ps -o comm,pid | egrep -e '^sh' | awk -F " " '{print $2}'`    
kill -9 $SH_PID

myprog #start my program

while true
do
        sleep 10
        echo "script is running..." > /dev/ttyS0
done
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't use `-9`; that's for debugging programs that don't respond properly. A simple `kill $SH_PID` should suffice.

Comment: Try doing that and you'l see that just `kill $SH_PID` doesn't work.

Comment: And please, don't down-vote if you are not sure what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

What if you kill your shell after running your program in background:

```
#!/bin/bash
SH_PID=`ps -o comm,pid | egrep -e '^sh' | awk -F " " '{print $2}'`    

nohup myprog & #start my program in background

kill --HUP $SH_PID

while true
do
        sleep 10
        echo "script is running..." > /dev/ttyS0
done
```

Comment: I think that if you `kill -9` there's no way to have `myprog` to ignore it. You should run `nohup myprog; kill -HUP $SH_PID` and it may work but I doubt that the `while` loop will be executed anyway.

Comment: @Oberix I think the while loop is there to see if the kill worked

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I can't start myprog before I get sh process killed, as myprog should open /dev/ttyS0 which is used by sh process. If I change the order myprog starts it will not work. It must start only after sh gets killed.

Comment: @SSA can you put a timer in the beginning of your program so it waits for the shell to be killed ?

Comment: I thought about it, but, unfortunately, I don't have sources. After a series of tests I've noticed that myprog doesn't start without being logged in. I mean, it doesn't start when getty or sh is killed. May be it's somehow linked with user rights and don't know how.